# Repopulate an array list once emptied

Tags: java, android, arraylist

What I have currently is a game where the user presses a sprite and when pressed it will add to their score and then will make it so that the sprite will disappear. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to make the sprites reappear once they are pressed as they are being removed from the array list completely, would I readd these to the array list or would I do it in a different way?

This is the sprite code:

```
package cct.mad.lab;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;  
import android.os.Vibrator;
public class Sprite {

    //x,y position of sprite - initial position (0,50)
    private GameView gameView;
    private Bitmap spritebmp;
    //Width and Height of the Sprite image
    private int bmp_width;
    private int bmp_height;
    // Needed for new random coordinates.
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int x = random.nextInt(200)-1; 
    private int y = random.nextInt(200)-1;
    int xSpeed = (random.nextInt(30)-15);
    int ySpeed = (random.nextInt(30)-15);

    public Sprite(GameView gameView) {
        this.gameView=gameView;
        spritebmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameView.getResources(),
          R.drawable.spritehead);
        this.bmp_width = spritebmp.getWidth();
        this.bmp_height= spritebmp.getHeight();
        //random y coordinate for sprite spawn
        x = gameView.getWidth();
        x = random.nextInt(x);
        y = gameView.getHeight();
        y = random.nextInt(y);
    }

    //update the position of the sprite
    public void update() {
        x = x + xSpeed;
        y = y + ySpeed;
        wrapAround(); //Adjust motion of sprite.
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw sprite image
        canvas.drawBitmap(spritebmp, x , y, null);
    }

    //y -= gameView.getHeight();//Reset y
    public void wrapAround(){
        //Code to wrap around   
        //increment x whilst not off screen
        if (x >= (gameView.getWidth() - 40)){ //if gone off the right sides of screen
            xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
        }
        if (x <= -10)
        {
            xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
        }

        if (y >= (gameView.getHeight() - 40)){//if gone off the bottom of screen
            ySpeed = (ySpeed * -1);
        }

        if (y <= 0)//if gone off the top of the screen
        {
            ySpeed = (ySpeed * -1);
        }
        xSpeed = (xSpeed * -1);
    }


    /* Checks if the Sprite was touched. */
    public boolean wasItTouched(float ex, float ey) {
        boolean touched = false; 
        if ((x <= ex) && (ex < x + bmp_width) &&
                (y <= ey) && (ey < y + bmp_height)) {
            touched = true;
        }
        return touched;
    }//End of wasItTouched 
}
```

and this is my code for actually displaying the items and the array list:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);

    for (int sp =0; spritesArrayList.size() < spNumber; sp++) {
        spritesArrayList.add(sprite = new Sprite(this));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it won't work

Comment: Where you define/initialize `spritesArrayList`?

Comment: It's just this :    private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;
    int spNumber = 5; @mikekeepsonshine

Comment: please post the code where `spritesArrayList` is initialized and operated upon.

Answer (score 0):

When i have to add/remove items from an Object, usually i use an `HashMap`.

In your case, something like `HashMap<String,Sprite>`, so you can add/remove items identifying them through the the Hash key.

e.g.

```
//HashMap<String,Sprite> hashSprite
//add
hashSprite.put("sprite1",new Sprite(this));
//remove 
hashSprite.remove("sprite1")
```

I know that it's not a real answer, but as a suggestion could be appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?